# Executor Thread Pool - limit queue size and dequeue oldest

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, threadpoolexecutor

I am using a fixed thread pool for a consumer of produced messages within a spring boot application. My producer is producing (a lot) faster than the producer is able to handle a message, therefore the queue of the thread pool seems to be "flooding".

What would be the best way to limit the queue size? The intended queue behaviour would be "if the queue is full, remove the head and insert the new Runnable". Is it possible to configure Executors thread pool like this?

Comment: Have you looked at [RejectedExecutionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionHandler.html)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ThreadPoolExecutor` supports this function via [`ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy.html):

> A handler for rejected tasks that discards the oldest unhandled
>   request and then retries execute, unless the executor is shut down, in
>   which case the task is discarded.

You need to construct the pool with this policy mannully, for exmaple:

```
int poolSize = ...;
int queueSize = ...;
RejectedExecutionHandler handler = new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardOldestPolicy();

ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(poolSize, poolSize,
    0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
    new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(queueSize),
    handler);
```

Comment: Could be exactly what I am searching for. But I am not sure if I get "A handler for rejected tasks that discards the oldest unhandled request and then retries execute" right. Is the oldest task rejected or is it just postponed to a later step? I'd like to complete discard and delete the oldest entry in my queue.

Comment: @user6903701 oldest will be deleted

Answer (score 0):

This will create a thread pool for you of the size that you pass.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_SIZE);
```

This internally creates an instance of ThreadPoolExecutor, which implements ExecutorService.

```
public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                                  0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                  new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
}
```

To create a custom thead pool, you can just do.

```
ExecutorService service =   new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 5,
                                  0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                  new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(10));
```

Here we can specify the size of the queue, using the overloaded constructor of the LinkedBlockingQueue.

```
    public LinkedBlockingQueue(int capacity) {
        if (capacity <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.capacity = capacity;
        last = head = new Node<E>(null);
    }
```

Hope this helps. Cheers !!!

Comment: I don't think this is an acceptable answer. 

OP asked "What would be the best way to limit the queue size? The intended queue behaviour would be "if the queue is full, remove the head and insert the new Runnable". 

So the real reason you'd use ThreadPoolExecutor directly is to be able to specify the blocking queue's policy. (As answered by xingbin above).

Answer (score 0):

For example if you working with Data Base(psql) which has capable of 100 connections at a time . and task may takes 2000ms ...

````
        int THREADS = 50;
        ExecutorService exe = new ThreadPoolExecutor(THREADS,
                                                    50,
                                                    0L,
                                                     TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                                     new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10),
                                                     new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy()); ```
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).